# Getting the number of the issued SQL statements for a specific table

Tags: monitoring, firebird

I am using firebird DB, and for testing reasons I want to know how many times a specific table has been accessed, without doing it manually with some counter in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird does not keep a historical record of table access. You might be able to use the Firebird trace facility to track this yourself, but this requires the trace to be active the whole time (which can have an impact on performance), alternatively you can use third-party (paid) tools like FBScanner.

You can also try to use the monitoring tables, specifically `MON$RECORD_STATS`, but those statistics are only maintained for as long as the database is open (ie has active connections), once the last connection is closed (and assuming database linger is off) the database gets closed, those statistics are expunged.

`MON$RECORD_STATS` does not contain table access itself, but things like number of records read, inserted, deleted, etc. Associated tables can be found through `RDB$TABLE_STATS`:

```sql
select t.MON$TABLE_NAME, r.MON$STAT_ID, r.MON$STAT_GROUP, r.MON$RECORD_SEQ_READS,
    r.MON$RECORD_IDX_READS, r.MON$RECORD_INSERTS, r.MON$RECORD_UPDATES,
    r.MON$RECORD_DELETES, r.MON$RECORD_BACKOUTS, r.MON$RECORD_PURGES,
    r.MON$RECORD_EXPUNGES, r.MON$RECORD_LOCKS, r.MON$RECORD_WAITS,
    r.MON$RECORD_CONFLICTS, r.MON$BACKVERSION_READS, r.MON$FRAGMENT_READS,
    r.MON$RECORD_RPT_READS
from MON$TABLE_STATS t
inner join MON$RECORD_STATS r
    on t.MON$STAT_GROUP = r.MON$STAT_GROUP and t.MON$RECORD_STAT_ID = r.MON$STAT_ID
```

For details see `doc/README.monitoring_tables.txt` in your Firebird install, or [README.monitoring_tables.txt (Firebird 3)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/B3_0_Release/doc/README.monitoring_tables).